# pthread_join usage

Tags: c++, join, pthreads

What happens if i call pthread_join(NULL) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first of the two expected arguments to pthread_join() is NULL, anything (bad) can happen at runtime. From the specification at www.opengroup.org: "**The behavior is undefined** if the value specified by the thread argument to pthread_join() does not refer to a joinable thread."

NULL is accepted for the second argument of pthread_join().

EDIT: Indeed some implementations can specify the behavior. Check man page for pthread_join on your system.

Comment: Some implementations define this behavior, for example Linux man page claims it would return immediately with `errno` set to `ESRCH` if thread_id does not correspond to a thread (although for me it simply crashes when passed NULL)

Comment: @Cubbi: a valid observation; thanks! - but sounds like in practice it still can be UB?

Comment: keep citing from specs but can't tell the man the first arg is an unsigned long int passed by value, not a pointer. /usr/include/bits/pthreadtypes.h:typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;  function signature: int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr);

Comment: @adirau: he did not specify the system, so I think the best is to consider pthread_t an opaque type. But the compiler may well accept NULL passed for pthread_t; and in case of unsigned long, it will. So, what do you actually want to say?

Comment: altho the spec is defining pthread_t only as an arithmetic type (so it can be of any type with bound arithmetics i assume, including pointer type), there's no implementation whatsoever, at least between the well knowns, that are defining pthread_t as being something else than an integral big enough to hold a thread id. correct me if i'm wrong. from my point of view there's nothing opaque about pthread_t unless you just wanna look cool

Comment: @adirau: I did not look into details of all well known implementations to judge about what they do. And I still can't understand what's the point you tried to make - should I have said that he should not pass NULL into pthread_join, or what? Well, the spec says that well enough :) And, I give +1 to your answer because it's the most correct for the question.

Comment: @adirau: `NULL` is not a pointer, in C++ mode it's `0` and will happily be passed around as `int`

Comment: @sbk: in C is a constant as well, (void *)0. Yes you can pass it around but I think your C++ compiler wouldnt be totally happy to see something like int a = 1 + NULL; nor your boss. I know when you are seeing NULL in some C++ code you are thinking of a pointer, not of an int; how often did you initialize an int with a NULL ? int a = NULL;  Want me to agree that pthread_join(NULL,NULL)  is valid C++ code? Ok. I will agree to some extent that Kukanov, being a C++ programmer, by using NULL as the first arg, wanted to signify something undefined. Or opaque. Or just something. I'm good with it.

Answer (score 10):

you get a compile time error; `pthread_join()` expects 2 arguments :)

Comment: suppose i call it with NULL,NULL - will it be okay? (Or is it waiting for a non-NULL pthread?)

Comment: it expects a valid thread id (an unsigned long int) as the first parameter and eventually a pointer to a buffer you know what you are expecting in from pthread_exit(); if you dont know then you can use NULL as the second param; you can also use NULL instead of an int as the first parameter but I would advise against it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would **always check the function return**:

```
if (0 != pthread_join(thread, &result)) 
{
   fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join error\n");
}
```

> If successful, the pthread_join() function returns zero. Otherwise, an error number is returned to indicate the error.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you try to pass to the function, check the return and you'll know what happens!

Comment: yea, if you ever get to check that :)